# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable warning by using .GetType()

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, enumerator, gettype

I get the ReSharper warning "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" with following code:

```
public void Mymethod(IEnumerable<int> entities)
{
   var enumerator = entities.GetEnumerator();
   var entityType = entities.GetType();
}
```

As in much stackoverflow-topics described (and also on http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable) ReSharper recognizes that the query runs twice.

My question is, why the "GetType()" statement is recognized as a query.

Any suggestion?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's referring to the `enumerator` line.  It's probably looking for a corresponding `Dispose()` call on it.

Comment: I get the warning for both statements. It also occurs if I only call .GetType() two times instead of .GetEnumerator()

Comment: [I've submitted this as an issue to the ReSharper bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288467)

Comment: @AakashM: thanks for submitting in but tracker. looks like bug will be fixed in next version. I look forward to the update ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's just Resharper not being smart enough. `GetType` isn't a virtual method, it can't affect the `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `GetTypes` to be invoked, `entities` will need to be evaluated from ReSharper's point of view (it doesn't know whether `GetTypes` will require the enumeration to be evaluated, that's why it says "*possible* multiple enumeration"). Since ReSharper sees that there are several locations within the method where you have the same scenario, it issues this warning.

This may or may not be a problem, depending on what `entities` represents and what operation you perform on it. If it represents an in-memory array, or you perform an operation that does not iterate over the list, it's not much to worry about. If you iterate over it, and it represents a query that will go to a database, it's probably good to enumerate it explicitly (by calling `ToList` or `ToArray`) and act on the result of that instead.

Comment: `entities` is an object in a certain state. How can a call to [object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) change this state?

Comment: @dtb: I was a bit unclear; this is speaking from ReSharper's point of view. Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the answer to clarify that.